# How to convert a pretrained tensorflow pb frozen graph into a modifiable h5 keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have been searching for a method to do this for so long, and I can not find an answer. Most threads I found are of people wanting to do the opposite.

**Backstory:**

I am experimenting with some pre-trained models provided by the [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repository. The models are saved as .pb frozen graphs. I want to fine-tune some of these models by changing the final layers to suit my application.

Hence, I want to load the models inside a jupyter notebook as a normal keras h5 model.

How can I do that?
do you have a better way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

seems like all you would have to do is download the model files and store them in a directory. Call the directory for example c:\models. Then load the model.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r'c:\models')
model.summary()  # prints out the model layers
# generate code to modify the model as you typically do for transfer learning
# compile  the changed model
# train the model
# save the trained model as a .h5 file
dir=r'path to the directory you want to save the model to'
model_identifier= 'abcd.h5' # for abcd use whatever  identification you want
save_path=os.path.join(dir, model_identifier)
model.save(save_path)
```

Comment: This does not work. As I think "saved model" type is different from frozen graphs, although both may have the same .pb extension. When trying the above code, you would get "AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'summary'" @ model.summary()

Comment: guess it must be as you say. I have no experience with "frozen graphs" but use saved models all the time. Hope someone can give you the solution. I did  find some documentation on the subject at https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc. It looks like it has the code to load and use frozen models.